# Colorama and the grid challenge from automate the boring stuff book: I want to paint the heart

Tags: python, colorama

In the "automate the boring stuff" textbook, there is a challenge where you are given a grid and you have to flip it over. I could understand grids with lists of lists and came to a solution that works, so that part of the challenge is done.

I would like to color the heart red with a green background. Just for playing around.

Here's the code I came up with:

```
from colorama import Fore, init
init()

#this is the original grid given by the book. we have to use it to print a heart

grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]


heart=[]

#This reorder the grid inside a new empty list. Still struggling to understand it fully but i think i got it. Its a bit weird but i get the idea 



for x in range(len(grid[1])):
      for i in range(len(grid)):
            heart.append(grid[i][x])

#these two will be of use to tell the program wether to colour a character green or not

dot=['.']
circle=['O']

#this makes it so it prints no more than 9 characters per list. The nested if/elses are for the colours. I tried if/and, if/if and a couple more i cant remember

for index, item in enumerate(heart):
      if ((index+1)%9==0):
            if item in dot:
                  print(Fore.GREEN+item)

            else:
                  print(Fore.RED+item)

      else :
            if item in dot:
                  print(Fore.GREEN+item, end=" ")


            else:
                  print(Fore.RED+item, end=" ")
```

The output so far is 75% done. There is a heart, there are colors... but for whatever reason, the coloring is all wrong:

[image: output]

What could be wrong?

Comment: Unable to reproduce the problem. Your code works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. I really dont know how. First i tried to do it with Colored module. Same issue. I restored the code to this version, closed and opened the file, ran it and voila! It solved itself. I know there is a technical and easy explanation but the thing is, the most basic of solutions worked.
The output is as it should be: red heart surrounded by green spots. At least the code was always right. So, that was it. Next time something similar happens, i´ll just "turn it off and on again"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).